# Why is MySQL MariaDB GREATEST(timestamp,NOW()) padding appending results with zeros?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Everything works as expected on my development machine, but when deploying to quality assurance environment, tests are failing because MariaDB is padding the result set with extra precision zeros after a decimal.

For example, when I run this query:

```
SELECT GREATEST(  '2016-04-14 15:06:30', NOW() )
```

On dev, running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (Trusty Tahr) mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.47, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3, I get this expected result:

> 2016-04-18 09:07:42

On test, running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.2 (Maipo) mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.44-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1, I get this **un**expected result:

> 2016-04-18 09:07:42.000000

I don't see anything in the [`GREATEST()` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) that would explain this behavior, so I think it must be a server configuration setting in `my.cnf` but I couldn't find anything in online search results.

Even more curiously, when running the following queries, I get the same **unpadded** results on *both* machines:

```
SELECT GREATEST(  '2016-04-14 15:06:30', '2016-04-14 16:06:30' )
```

> 2016-04-14 16:06:30

```
SELECT GREATEST(  NOW(), NOW() )
```

> 2016-04-18 09:24:22

```
SELECT GREATEST(  5, 10 )
```

> 10

**Why is MariaDB `GREATEST()` padding/appending my result set with zeros on timestamp comparison with `NOW()`?**

Comment: What do you get if you cast `now()` to `timestamp` or `datetime(0)`, eg with `SELECT GREATEST(  '2016-04-14 15:06:30', CAST(NOW() AS TIMESTAMP))`?

Comment: `select greatest('2016-04-02 12:24:52',cast(now() as datetime(0)))` results in `2016-04-18 14:17:22.000000` on both servers

Comment: Interesting. And `SELECT GREATEST(NOW(), '2016-04-14 15:06:30');` ?

Comment: `SELECT GREATEST(NOW(), '2016-04-14 15:06:30');` results in `2016-04-18 14:43:16` on Ubuntu, and `2016-04-18 14:46:49.000000` on RedHat.

Comment: I apologize for my previous comment, that was only the result on RedHat. `select greatest('2016-04-02 12:24:52',cast(now() as datetime(0)))` on Ubuntu results in an error `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(0)))' at line 1`

Comment: `SELECT GREATEST( '2016-04-14 15:06:30', CAST(NOW() AS TIMESTAMP))` results in an error on *both* machines: `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TIMESTAMP))' at line 1`

Comment: Sorry for the many comments, I just don't have MariaDB available at the moment to test. Can you try a last one (in MariaDB)?: `SELECT GREATEST(NOW(), TIMESTAMP '2016-04-14 15:06:30');`

Comment: I assume you didn't mean that first comma, which resulted in error, but `SELECT GREATEST(NOW(), TIMESTAMP '2016-04-14 15:06:30')` on Maria results in `2016-04-18 14:59:50.000000`, which is surprising considering the timestamp literal from the posted answer doesn't work, while `STR_TO_DATE` does.

Comment: The correct answer that would work in both servers would probably involve `DATE_FORMAT`, similarly to what is suggested in the answer but with reverse order: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT( GREATEST(NOW(), '2016-04-14 15:06:30'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');` First compare the values, then convert to the format you want for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MariaDB doku](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/now/) claims for `NOW()`:

> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
>   or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, **depending on whether the function is
>   used in a string or numeric context**.

So this might be related to the fact that `'2016-04-14 15:06:30'` may look like a timestamp, but is actually a Varchar.

Try using *timestamp literals*:

```
SELECT GREATEST( TIMESTAMP '2016-04-14 15:06:30', NOW() )
```

Or [functional conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT GREATEST( STR_TO_DATE('2016-04-14 15:06:31','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), NOW() )
```

Comment: I definitely think you're on to something, but `SELECT GREATEST( TIMESTAMP '2016-04-14 15:06:30', NOW() )` still returns `2016-04-18 13:10:15.000000`

Comment: I found a solution using your recommendation by [explicitly converting string to date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). If you accept my edits, then I'll mark it as the answer